# Getting JS to read the selection from a HTML <select> form

Tags: javascript, html, onchange

I am trying to write a piece of JS code that will get the selected option from a HTML `<select>` form, read it and then give me something back depending on what the option was.

The HTML code looks like this:

```
<select id="mainhand" name="Main hand" onchange="getmh()">
    <option value="Sword" selected> Sword </option>
    <option value="Axe"> Axe </option>
    <option value="Mace"> Mace </option>
</select>
<p id="mhchoice">choice</p> 
<p id="mhdesc">description</p>
<p id="mhcost">cost</p>
```

and the JS like this:

```
function getmh(option){
    if (option == "Sword"){
       document.getElementById('mhchoice').innerHTML = 'Sword';
       document.getElementById('mhdesc').innerHTML = swordDesc;
       document.getElementById('mhcost').innerHTML = swordPrice;
       document.getElementById('ProductImage').src = 'sword.png';
    }
    if (option == "Axe"){
        document.getElementById('mhchoice').innerHTML = 'Axe';
        document.getElementById('mhdesc').innerHTML = axeDesc;
        document.getElementById('mhcost').innerHTML = axePrice;
        document.getElementById('ProductImage').src = 'axe.png';
    }    
    if (option == "Mace"){
        document.getElementById('mhchoice').innerHTML = 'Mace';
        document.getElementById('mhdesc').innerHTML = maceDesc;
        document.getElementById('mhcost').innerHTML = macePrice;
        document.getElementById('ProductImage').src = 'mace.png';
    }   
}
```

I've been stuck on this for nearly two hours now, I've tried multiple things but nothing seems to work so far.

Comment: And `option` inside the function is supposed to magically get a value from where exactly, if you are not passing any parameter in the function call ...?

Comment: @arszenik if you get -1 it meas your solution is easy you are missing something like out of sight out of mind.

Comment: `onchange="getmh(this.value)"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **@nnnnnn** mentioned in the **[Above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40314169/getting-js-to-read-the-selection-from-a-html-select-form/40314253#comment-67885637)**, you've just to pass the selected value `this.value` to the function :

```
<select id="mainhand" name="Main hand" onchange="getmh(this.value)">
```

Hope this helps.

```js
function getmh(option){
  if (option == "Sword"){
    document.getElementById('mhchoice').innerHTML = 'Sword';
    document.getElementById('mhdesc').innerHTML = swordDesc;
    document.getElementById('mhcost').innerHTML = swordPrice;
    document.getElementById('ProductImage').src = 'sword.png';
  }
  if (option == "Axe"){
    document.getElementById('mhchoice').innerHTML = 'Axe';
    document.getElementById('mhdesc').innerHTML = axeDesc;
    document.getElementById('mhcost').innerHTML = axePrice;
    document.getElementById('ProductImage').src = 'axe.png';
  }    
  if (option == "Mace"){
    document.getElementById('mhchoice').innerHTML = 'Mace';
    document.getElementById('mhdesc').innerHTML = maceDesc;
    document.getElementById('mhcost').innerHTML = macePrice;
    document.getElementById('ProductImage').src = 'mace.png';
  }   
}
```

```html
<select id="mainhand" name="Main hand" onchange="getmh(this.value)">
  <option value="Sword" selected> Sword </option>
  <option value="Axe"> Axe </option>
  <option value="Mace"> Mace </option>
</select>
<p id="mhchoice">choice</p> 
<p id="mhdesc">description</p>
<p id="mhcost">cost</p>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that got it to work, though I wasted the past hour on this until I realised I was also missing a " } "

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going for the LONG path.
You can try something like this.

```
<select id="myValue" onchange="CheckValue()">
    <option value="1">Uno</option>
    <option value="2">Dos</option>
    <option value="3">Tres</option>
</select>
<script>
    function CheckValue() {
        var value = document.getElementById("myValue").value;

        switch (value) {
            // all your conditions
            default:
                //
        }
    }
</script>
```